# Что означает "tab" в программировании?

Tags: терминология

Читаю книжечку "Code Conventions" и наткнулся на эту не до конца понятную для себя вещь:

Вот предложение

> Indentation.
>   Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4).

Переведите дословно, пожалуйста, что означает слово "TAB" или "TABS" в русском языке?
Гугл переводит, как "вкладка", но не до конца понятно это.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: В контексте программирования `tab` означает отступ (от начала строки).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, есть с этим путаница. У вас, во втором предложении "The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified", под "tabs" подразумеваются символы табуляции. Но тут же в третьем предложении "Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)", под "Tabs" имеются в виду отступы от левой границы.

Дело в том, в соглашениях об оформлении кода регламентируется количество пробелов которое должен содержать такой отступ. В программистских редакторах кода всегда есть соответствующая настройка. Дополнительно в соглашениях может оговариваться обязательно ли заменять символы табуляции, которые вводятся собственно клавишей TAB, на оговоренное количество пробелов. И получается, что одно нажатие клавиши TAB вводит один отступ, поэтому отступы и называют табами.

Все эти соглашения нужны для того, чтобы все участники команды видели бы текст программы одинаково так же, как его отформатировал автор. А иначе, если настройки не будут согласованы, то форматирование "уедет".

Comment: От левой границы.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ваша правда

Answer (score 3):

Подразумевается клавиша "Tab" на клавиатуре.

Comment: Нет, в данном контексте это не так. Имеется в виду символ табуляции. А с помощью чего он введен - с клавиатуры или кодом '\t' - не важно

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вы текст на компе кодами набираете?

Comment: @Cerbo - я часто генерирую код программно.